# Issue while setting up sectionList from phone contacts when First or last name are nulls

Tags: iphone, ios

I was wondering if somebody can help with an issue I am facing. I have
retrieved the phone contacts using the standard way (I have to sort by lastName)

```
NSMutableArray *contactArray = [NSMutableArray array]; 
CFArrayRef people = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook); 
CFMutableArrayRef peopleMutable = CFArrayCreateMutableCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault,CFArrayGetCount(people), people);

CFArraySortValues(peopleMutable, CFRangeMake(0,
CFArrayGetCount(peopleMutable)),
(CFComparatorFunction)ABPersonComparePeopleByName, (void
*)kABPersonSortByLastName);

NSArray *allPeopleArray = (NSArray *)peopleMutable;
```

I loop thru each record and populate a NSMutableDictionary with
kABPersonFirstNameProperty, kABPersonLastNameProperty,
kABPersonEmailProperty, kABPersonPhoneProperty. Some of the contacts
does not have a firstName or a lastName. So I do check for them and
populate the MutableDictionary with [NSNull null] for either the firstName of the lastName. Now I need to sort
this MutableArray. I use NSSortDescriptor to sort

```
NSSortDescriptor *aSortDescriptor1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"lastName" ascending:YES];
NSSortDescriptor *aSortDescriptor2 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"firstName" ascending:YES]; 
[listToSort sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:aSortDescriptor1, aSortDescriptor2, nil]];
[aSortDescriptor1 release]; 
[aSortDescriptor2 release];
```

when I NSLog listToSort the list is sorted correctly.

I then pass this sorted mutable array to this method which basically creates a sectionList for displaying on a UItableview

```
-(void)setupSectionList:(NSMutableArray *)contactList {
sectionNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
sectionData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSString *previous=@"";
for (NSDictionary *dict in contactList) {
    NSString *lastName = [dict objectForKey:@"lastName"];
    NSString *firstName = [dict objectForKey:@"firstName"];

    NSString *firstLetter = nil;
    if ([dict objectForKey:@"lastName"] != [NSNull null]) {
        firstLetter = [lastName substringToIndex:1];
    }else if ([dict objectForKey:@"firstName"] != [NSNull null]) {
        firstLetter = [firstName substringToIndex:1];
    }
    //Get the first Letter

    if (firstLetter) {
        //Add the letter to sectioNames when it is different
        if (![firstLetter isEqualToString:previous]) {
            previous = firstLetter;
            [sectionNames addObject:[firstLetter uppercaseString]];
            //Now add a new array to our array of arrays
            NSMutableArray *oneSection = [NSMutableArray array];
            [sectionData addObject:oneSection];
        }
        //Add this dictionary to the last section array
        [[sectionData lastObject] addObject:dict];
    }
}
}
```

here is where the sort gets messed up. here is an example. I have contact that has only a firstName as FirstName and nothing else. I also have 2 other contacts John Appleseed and William Frank. When I NSLog the sectionData from the above code, I see the first letters 
as F, A, F. I was hoping to see A, F. Can somebody help me on how to address this issue? Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this check:

```
if (![firstLetter isEqualToString:previous])
```

Try this:

```
if ([sectionNames indexOfObject:firstLetter] == NSNotFound)
```

To determine if you already have this first letter.

Comment: Thank you for responding. With the above suggestion, sectionNames will always be empty since nothing has been added to it.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `==` not `!=`. Check it again now.

Comment: Geez..Sorry...Stupid me..Should have caught that. I have been under lot of stress to finish off a project and have been working like crazy so missed this royally. That worked. Thanks again for your help.